# Create Date and Datetime Sequences in Julia

Tags: date, datetime, julia

How can I create a `Date` or `DateTime` sequence in Julia, e.g. all hours between midnight and 10 am, or all dates between January, 1st and February, 1st.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Julia provides some very intuitive functionality in the `Dates` package for this. You can simply create a range as you would with other types as well. (And turn them into a vector with `collect()` if so desired. In the center you can define the step size.

```
Date(2022,01,01):Day(1):Date(2022,01,04) |> collect

4-element Vector{Date}:
 2022-01-01
 2022-01-02
 2022-01-03
 2022-01-04
```

And for datetimes it is the same:

```
DateTime(2022,01,01,00,00,00):Second(1):DateTime(2022,01,01,00,00,10) |> collect

11-element Vector{DateTime}:
 2022-01-01T00:00:00
 2022-01-01T00:00:01
 2022-01-01T00:00:02
 2022-01-01T00:00:03
 2022-01-01T00:00:04
 2022-01-01T00:00:05
 2022-01-01T00:00:06
 2022-01-01T00:00:07
 2022-01-01T00:00:08
 2022-01-01T00:00:09
 2022-01-01T00:00:10
```